# Can't get list of files from google drive using php

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I am working with google drive API with PHP. Basically i create a auth credentials   and stuck at a point where i want to list of google drive files. Here is my code which i try.

```
<?php
require_once realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/gac/src/Google/autoload.php');

$client = new Google_Client();

session_start();

$client->setClientId('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
$client->setClientSecret('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://www.my-website-name.com/drive_test');
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'));

if (isset($_GET['code']) || (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token'])) {
    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
        $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    } else
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

    $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

    echo "<pre>";
    $all_files = "";
    $all_files = retrieveAllFiles($service);
    print_r($all_files);
    die;

} else {
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    header('Location: ' . $authUrl);
    exit();
}


/**
 * Retrieve a list of File resources.
 *
 * @param Google_Service_Drive $service Drive API service instance.
 * @return Array List of Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile resources.
 */
function retrieveAllFiles($service) {
  $result = array();
  $pageToken = NULL;

  do {
    try {
      $parameters = array();
      if ($pageToken) {
        $parameters['pageToken'] = $pageToken;
      }
      $files = $service->files->listFiles($parameters);

      $result = array_merge($result, $files->getItems());
      $pageToken = $files->getNextPageToken();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
      $pageToken = NULL;
    }
  } while ($pageToken);
  return $result;
}
```

?>

**I am getting output like this.**

```
Array
(
)
```

Please help me to solve this issue. Thank you.

Comment: just after this line `$files = $service->files->listFiles($parameters);`, try  `var_dump($files);` and then `var_dump($files->getItems())` and see whats output?

Comment: @atom i am getting something like this http://pastebin.com/SkLbK5dD

Comment: well it looks like its connected. Do you need to provide access to the files before they can be viewed?

Comment: at the bottom of this page, there is an option to try and access the results. Maybe check that you can access them as expected here.
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list

Comment: @atom, Basically there are some shared files/folders and some of mine. So i don't figure out what to do with it. Can you check my code above and give me some hint or solution based on that. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: try checking you can access the files using the link/tool supplied. IF you can access them here, we know its not a permission issue.

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't help me. If i have files in trash then above code can fetch and display it. But can not fetch files not in trash folder.

Comment: so maybe its a permission issue, rather that the code you have there. Will have a read on the API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh yes, finally i found the issue and fix it. It's a permission issue. I just replace this code

```
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'));
```

With new code

```
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));
```

and everythig